# Use two entities with the same name in symfony

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony

Hi i need to use two entities with the same name but from a different bundle

Here is how i insert data in my db

```
use StudentsBundle\Entity\logintrys;

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();          
$start = new logintrys();
$start->setStudentId($username);
$start->setLogintrys($array);

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$em->persist($start);

$em->flush();
```

And the entity class

```
<?php

namespace StudentsBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * logintrys
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="logintrys")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="StudentsBundle\Repository\logintrysRepository")
 */
class logintrys
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="student_id", type="string", length=20)
     */
    private $studentId;

    /**
     * @var array
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="logintrys", type="json_array", nullable=true)
     */
    private $logintrys;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set studentId
     *
     * @param string $studentId
     *
     * @return logintrys
     */
    public function setStudentId($studentId)
    {
        $this->studentId = $studentId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get studentId
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getStudentId()
    {
        return $this->studentId;
    }

    /**
     * Set logintrys
     *
     * @param array $logintrys
     *
     * @return logintrys
     */
    public function setLogintrys($logintrys)
    {
        $this->logintrys = $logintrys;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get logintrys
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getLogintrys()
    {
        return $this->logintrys;
    }
}
```

My second insert query is exactly the same as the first one only now i can not use $start = new logintrys(); because this is the same name as the first

here is my entity in the teachersBundle

```
<?php

namespace TeachersBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * logintrys
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="logintrys")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="TeachersBundle\Repository\logintrysRepository")
 */
class logintrys
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="docent_id", type="string", length=20)
     */
    private $docentId;

    /**
     * @var array
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="logintrys", type="json_array", nullable=true)
     */
    private $logintrys;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set docentId
     *
     * @param string $docentId
     *
     * @return logintrys
     */
    public function setDocentId($docentId)
    {
        $this->docentId = $docentId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get docentId
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDocentId()
    {
        return $this->docentId;
    }

    /**
     * Set logintrys
     *
     * @param array $logintrys
     *
     * @return logintrys
     */
    public function setLogintrys($logintrys)
    {
        $this->logintrys = $logintrys;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get logintrys
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getLogintrys()
    {
        return $this->logintrys;
    }
}
```

My question is how can i use the logintrys of the StudentsBundle and TeachersBundle in the same script

**Here is the error**

Cannot use TeachersBundle\Entity\logintrys as logintrys because the name is already in use

Thank you in advance

Comment: What's the problem of use both?

Comment: Cannot use TeachersBundle\Entity\logintrys as logintrys because the name is already in use     that is the problem

Comment: use TeachersBundle\Entity\logintrys as Teacherlogintrys;

$teacherLogin = new Teacherlogintrys();

Comment: that fixes the first problem but i get this back SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'docent_id' in 'field list'

Comment: I think that the error is clear.

Answer (score 1):

When you call your entity with:

```
use StudentsBundle\Entity\logintrys;
```

you can add an 'as':

```
use StudentsBundle\Entity\logintrys as StudentLogintrys;
use TeachersBundle\Entity\logintrys as TeacherLogintrys;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

Then, in your code you can do:

```
$start = new StudentLogintrys();
$start2 = new TeacherLogintrys();
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that the better way is to use inheritance in which the main class contains your **logintrys** member.

because in php you can't do something like that :

```
use StudentsBundle\Entity\logintrys;
use TeachersBundle\Entity\logintrys;
```

this example provide an error because script don't know that kind of class you want instantiate.

I think this is a solution (there are always better but it should work) :

```
class father{    
    private logintrys
}

class student extends father{    
   private id;
   private studentId;
}

class teacher extends father{    
   private id;
   private docentId;
}
```

to create one of them :

```
$start = new father();
$start->setLogintrys($array);
if($start instanceof student) $start->setStudentId($username);
```